# What uses does the Camera item have?

Tags: spelunky-hd

In the XBLA port of Spelunky, there is a Camera item in some shops. The journal doesn't say anything much about it. It didn't seem to have any effect on the enemies I used it on, though it does stun damsels and I've heard it enrages shopkeepers.

Does this item have any useful purpose?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It stuns enemies as well providing you catch them in the "picture" box, and will light up dark levels when the flash goes off

I can also tell you from experience that people playing with you might not appreciate you flashing them repeatedly with it :)

**Update:** Just discovered it will kill undead and bats instantly too

Comment: It's true, most people don't appreciate being flashed :P

Comment: It will also anger the shopkeeper.  So do not take his picture, no matter how dashing he may look.

Comment: You can even stun the ghost (and get a great picture) with the camera.